# Question concerning markup validation errors

Tags: html, validation, markup

I am using [http://validator.w3.org/][1] for markup validation and I continue to get errors that don't make any sense to me. For two below, for example, the validator is telling me that there is an error detected within the closing brackets of the body and html tags. For one page it repeats these errors 5 times and it doesn't make sense to me. Any suggestions or help would be great, thanks! :)

Line 184, Column 7: XML Parsing Error: Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 17 and body

```
</body>
```

Error Line 185, Column 7: XML Parsing Error: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 16 and html

```
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see: `ending tag mismatch: div` - you're missing a `</div>` somewhere.
It can't figure out exactly where it's missing from, but it knows it must be somewhere before `</body>`